# Unable to bundle data in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, bundle, scope, instance-variables

I'm attempting to save the following data:

```
 @Override
    public void setMessageDetailsExpanded(MessageHeaderItem i, boolean expanded,
            int heightBefore) {
        mDiff = (expanded ? 1 : -1) * Math.abs(i.getHeight() - heightBefore);
        String mHeaderItem = i.toString();
        final boolean  mDetailsExpanded = expanded;
        int mHeightBefore = heightBefore;
    }
```

When setting a breakpoint above I see the data I'd like to bundle:

```
mMessageHeaderItem = com.android.mail.browse.ConversationViewAdapter$MessageHeaderItem@425a6f40

detailsExpanded = true 

heightBefore = 229
```

However when setting a breakpoint at onSaveInstanceState - it appears my output does not contain the data above?!

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putFloat(BUNDLE_KEY_WEBVIEW_Y_PERCENT, calculateScrollYPercent());
    outState.putBoolean(getTag(), mDetailsExpanded);
    outState.putInt(getTag(),  height);
    outState.putString(getTag(), mHeaderItem);

}


Im not sure why but for some reason when debugging the code above it contains the following: 



 mDetailsExpanded = False

    height = 0 

    mHeaderItem = null
```

I know I'm overlooking something small - but I can't seem to figure out why I'm not saving the data from `setMessageDetailsExpanded` in my bundle at `onSavedInstanceState`.

FULL SOURCE:

http://pastebin.com/Larzbwzh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First issue: you need to declare the variables you would like to use as class variables

```
public class MyClass {
     private int x;
     private String y;
     ....
```

then you can access them properly in other functions.

Second issue: call super after you save the variables you need on the bundle

```
outState.putString("myString", y);
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
```

Comment: Are you sure? Putting them afterwards (such as this):

http://pastebin.com/GW2VfkrR

Does not seem to be correct according to every example I have seen:

http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/03/save-and-restore-instance-state.html

http://android-am.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-saved-instance-state-bundle.html

Comment: here is the google example, done the way I suggested http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it... I changed my code flow to reflect yours - but I still can't seem to get the correct values for the data. Everything always returns mDetailsExpanded = False

    height = 0 

    mHeaderItem = null 


when it should be mMessageHeaderItem = com.android.mail.browse.ConversationViewAdapter$MessageHeaderItem@425a6f40

detailsExpanded = true 

heightBefore = 229


Therefore - I'm saving and restoring incorrect values :( 

Here's my full source (updated just now) if it helps:

http://pastebin.com/Larzbwzh

Comment: I believe the other answer to this question has pointed out the issue - but I'm not sure exactly how it can be corrected - how might I prevent the variables from being local to only setMessageDetailsExpanded? 

(apologies if this is a very simple/stupid question)

Comment: any variables you would like to use throughout the class should be declared just below the class declaration such as "Class Myclass { private int x; private String y; ... "   then they can be used anywhere in that class

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your variables mHeaderItem, mDetailsExpanded, mHeightBefore are local to / redefined in setMessageDetailsExpanded. So the assigned values are not seen in onSaveInstanceState.